# MKMapView keeps resetting back to the world view

Tags: iphone, memory, mkmapview, uitableview

Original question is below.
I fixed my problem.  I had the same view controller set for the tableview and the mapview.  AND I had all of my mapView init in viewDidLoad.  These both together made the following problems for me:

1) When the tab bar controller was presented modally and I received a memory warning the viewDidUnload was called (which I did nothing in before).  When the modal tab bar controller was dismissed and viewDidLoad was called, it reset my mapView.
2) When the tab bar controller was presented modally and I received a memory warning before moving to the tab with the view controller and then switched to that tab, my viewDidLoad was called in my mapView's controller which reset my map, AND it didn't reset the tables properties so that my tableView would not work.

Much thanks to Anomie for helping me debug this issue, and gain a better understanding of how these pieces are all connected.  Things work great now, and my App has a better design.

Original Question:
I have an application that has a mapview and when I present a tab bar view controller modally, every once in a while when I cancel the modal view controller the map resets back to the world view like a reset button was pressed on it.  A few details:

- This NEVER happens on the simulator
- I notice memory warnings around the time this happens on my device
- I do not do anything when memory warnings happen in my app, so nothing should have touched the mapview

Also, my tableview in my modal view controller sometimes shows up blank as well (aroudn the time of memory warnings).  When it comes up blank, the methods normally called to get the number of rows, sections, and data are not called at all.  Upon cancelling the modal view controller and re-opening it, the data is there fine, so the data is not getting erased..

Code I used to create the tab bar controller, picker and table:

```
ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *picker = [[ABPeoplePickerNavigationController alloc] init];
picker.peoplePickerDelegate = self;
// Display only a person's address(es)
NSArray *displayedItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInt:kABPersonAddressProperty],
                                                           nil];  
picker.displayedProperties = displayedItems;

UITabBarItem *peoplePickerTabBarItem = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTabBarSystemItem:UITabBarSystemItemContacts tag:0];
picker.tabBarItem = peoplePickerTabBarItem;

UITableViewController *tvc = [[UITableViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
tvc.tableView.delegate = self;
tvc.tableView.dataSource = self;
UINavigationController *nvc = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:tvc];
UIBarButtonItem *uibbiCancel = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(cancelTable)];
tvc.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = uibbiCancel;
tvc.title = @"Recents";
UITabBarItem *nvcTabBarItem = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTabBarSystemItem:UITabBarSystemItemRecents tag:2];
nvc.tabBarItem = nvcTabBarItem;

tbc = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];

NSArray *sections = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:picker, nvc, nil];

[tbc setViewControllers:sections];

[self presentModalViewController:tbc animated:YES];
[nvcTabBarItem release];
[uibbiCancel release];
[tvc release];
[peoplePickerTabBarItem release];
[picker release];
[nvc release];
[sections release];
[tbc release];
```

Comment: You can issue memory warnings in the simulator (in the Hardware menu). On the device you can do the same in the debugger: `call (void) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] _performMemoryWarning]`. Perhaps, this helps to debug the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your map view, what is probably happening is this: When a UIViewController is not being actively displayed (e.g. it is in a non-displayed tab of a UITabViewController, not the visible view in a UINavigationController, or is hidden by a modally presented view controller), it may release its view if a memory notification occurs. It will then recreate the view when needed.

For your table view, I'm not sure. Are you assigning the data source and delegate to the table view in the code that creates the containing view controller, rather than doing so in the view controller's `viewDidLoad` method?

Comment: or the datasource may be another thing that the phone is deciding it can get rid of.

Comment: @Walter: In that case, it would probably abort with EXC_BAD_ACCESS as the table view tried to call the data source methods rather than continue to run with no data.

Comment: @Anomie: That must be what is happening with the mapView.  It NEVER used to happen before when I just presented a ABPeoplePickerNavigationController modally, but when I switched and added this picker to a uitabbarcontroller along with recents and favorites it started happening.  Is there anything I can do from preventing it from getting rid of the mapview?
As far as the data table, I don't have a seperate view controllers viewDidLoad method.  I made everything link back to the same view controller I'm loading this all from.
More info posted in original thread

Comment: @Anomie: IS there a way I can prevent the mapview from being released?  It gets rid of all the pins the user searched for, the region, etc when it happens.

Comment: The problem with your table view is just as I suspected. To fix it, you'll need to either load the UITableViewController from a nib that binds the data source and delegate or subclass UITableViewController so you can set the data source and delegate in `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: For the map view, I don't see the code creating it above. You probably already have a UIViewController subclass for that one. If you're loading it from a nib you'll need to have the controller record the annotations and such in `viewDidUnload` (before releasing the ivar) so it can restore them in `viewDidLoad`; if you're doing it programmatically you could just not release the map view in `viewDidUnload` (and not re-create it if it already exists in `viewDidLoad`).

Comment: @anomie: I currently don't have anything in the `viewDidUnload` of the mapView's viewcontroller (which is the same viewcontroller I have everything in, which is probably a problem I need to remedy by seperating out the tableview into a seperate .h and .m).  I do have code in viewDidLoad though to setup the mapview, which is probably why it is getting reset even though I didn't purge it in `viewDidUnload`.  Thanks for the help on that, I should either do nothing in the `viewDidLoad` if the mapView already exists or do the releasing and recreating in load/unload.
RE:Table I'll give that a try

Comment: @anomie: IS it possible to just take the code I have in `viewDidLoad` and throw it somewhere else that will only happen once when my program is run.  I guess worst case is I store the current region and annotations (minus the userLocation) and re-add them to the map in `viewDidLoad`.  I'll give that a try when I get home, thanks again for all your help.  I think I'm understanding the hierchy of these things a little better now.

Comment: I wish I could give you rep anomie, but you helped me solve all my problems!  See original post for a blurb about it.  Thanks again!